# I want to query an MS Access database table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, database, ms-access-2013

The MS Access (2013) database has the following table ImportFromExcel (16 columns). I just want to see the table in a browser. Any help is appreciated :)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Import From Excel</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function query()
    {
        var pad = "C:\\Users\\azi!z\\Desktop\\Project\\Test.accdb";
        var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
        var strConn = "Provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;
        cn.Open(strConn);
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        var SQL = "SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel";
        rs.Open(SQL, cn);
        if(!rs.bof) 
        {
            rs.MoveFirst();
            if(!rs.eof)
            {
                document.write("<p>" + rs.fields(1).value + ", ");
                document.write(rs.fields(2).value + ", ");
                document.write(rs.fields(3).value + ".</p>");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("No data found");
        }
        rs.Close();
        cn.Close();
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: is this a typo? desktop var pad = "C:\\Users\\azi!z\\esktop\\Project\\Test.accdb";

Comment: Typo it is.* C:\\Users\\azi!z\\Desktop\\Project\\Test.accdb

Comment: great! if that solves your problem please accept my answer :)

Comment: You have a function named "query()", but it is never called and this results in a blank page.

Comment: Worked for me in IE by simply calling the query function after it is declared.

Comment: But, I believe if the function is placed within the <head> tag, we don't need to call it. It should be executed during page load. Am I right?

Comment: no you need to call it!

Comment: if you run my code below it should work... I am not using a function so it should just run it. Also I forgot to update your file path... so if it did not work make sure to update the file path.

Comment: Yo it worked :) Thank you very much @wuno Over the moon :D

Comment: Cool man accept the answer if it helped thanks man.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a typo in your code

`desktop` in your file path

```
var pad = "C:\\Users\\azi!z\\esktop\\Project\\Test.accdb";
```

If this is not the problem then please update your question and describe the problem instead of only the goal.

It appears you were not calling the function you declared in the `head`

Use this code below which is not in a function or call the function you declared.

Please this code,

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Access db Connection</title>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    var pad = "C:\\Users\\azi!z\\Desktop\\Project\\Test.accdb";

    //var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pad;
    var strConn = "Provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;

    var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");

    cn.Open(strConn);
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
   // var SQL = "SELECT * FROM customer_mas WHERE ID='512225'";
      var SQL = "SELECT * FROM ImportFromExcel";    
rs.Open(SQL, cn);
    if(!rs.bof) {
    rs.MoveFirst();
    if(!rs.eof) {
    document.write("<p><br>" + rs.fields(1).value + ", ");
    document.write("<br>" + rs.fields(2).value + ", ");
    document.write("<br>" + rs.fields(3).value + ".</p>");
    }
    }
    else {
    document.write("No data found");
    };
    rs.Close();
    cn.Close();

    </script>

    </head>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But, that's not the problem it seems. When I open the .html file, it's showing a blank page whereas, I'm expecting the table row to be displayed. *File path updated

Comment: Checked. No errors. Also, I have tried in both the browsers. IE 10 and mozilla.

Comment: Ya it is. I have uploaded the MS Access screenshot here https://unsee.cc/noguzepa/